# Java фризы во время выполнения

Tags: java, eclipse, libgdx, jvm, lwjgl

Собрал игру нa `LibGDX` в `Eclipse`, запускаю и каждые 10± секунд происходит дроп фреймрейта до 5-10 на пару секунд и освобождается 10Мб+ оперативной памяти. Думал проблема в том, что JVM запускается со стандартными значениями оперативной памяти. Прописал -Xms и -Xmx. Ничего не изменилось...

UPD. Тот же самый код собранный через `AIDE` в .apk не лагает, стабильно держится 60± фпс, вызовы `GC` видны по освобождению 3-4мб каждую секунду.

Все движения у меня происходят с использованием класса `Vector2`, при мониторинге через `VisualVM` как только кол-во объектов доходит до 4млн± происходит сбор мусора и в этот момент приложение провисает.

Comment: Без кода ничего конкретного вам посоветовать не получится. Скорее всего, у вас создаётся много объектов, которые вычищает сборщик мусора. Что это за объекты нужно выяснять с помощью профайлера.

Comment: @fori1ton созданные объекты не удаляются в процессе работы приложения.

Comment: @Asidert судя по освобождению _10Мб+ оперативной памяти_ таки удаляются. Но возможно созданные неявно. Осваивайте VisualVM или Java Mission Control и анализируйте использование _кучи_ вашей программой.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev таки тоже удивляюсь, спасибо за совет, буду копать в эту сторону.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev покопал, обновил вопрос

Comment: Нужен код, иначе можно гадать бесконечно.